# Is there any way to control the format of HTML generated by MVC 3 custom helper classes?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC 3 for web development, here when I create HTML using custom helper classes, it looks very ugly.

for example: If I build a list using helper, it gives me a result as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>some link 1</li>
<li>some link 2</li>
<li>some link 3</li>
<li>some link 4</li>
</ul>
```

What I need is, formatted HTML as follows:

```
<ul>
   <li>some link 1</li>
   <li>some link 2</li>
   <li>some link 3</li>
   <li>some link 4</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any native way available to achieve this?

Comment: This might cover it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593057/controlling-output-indentation-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: "DOM" isn't the right word. I think you mean just the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't matter because this only affects human readers of your rendered markup. I won't deny it is useful to have readable HTML, but how much time can you justify spending to work on getting this part "right"?

There are two main resolutions to this:

#### The first - process the generated HTML

With this approach, you get the `MvcHtmlString` returned from your helper function, then run that generated HTML fragment through a HTML formatting library. This approach will be very slow, as it has to render the unindented HTML, then parse and analyse it, then re-render it. Expect it to add up to 10ms to your page load time if you're using a heavy library to reformat the code or if you're sending it out to an external library for processing (e.g. a HtmlTidy executable).

#### The second - fix the HTML helper

The best way, of course, is to reimplement your HTML helper so it indents the code. Fortunately HTML Helpers don't tend to be too complicated. It isn't too hard to copy the generated source (using Reflector), then paste it into a new helper method with the right indentation.

This is, of course, assuming that the entire `<ul>` with all of its `<li>` elements is being made by a single Helper call, and not that you're omitting the indentation yourself in your view file.

Comment: With second approach, you mean, whether I need to add a \t and \n while building HTML kind of?

Comment: Yes. You would have something like this: `HtmlTextWriter wtr; wtr.Write("\r\n\t\t\t<li>");`. or `wtr.Indent++;`.